# CASE Statement in WHERE Clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble sorting this out. I want to see the fiscal quarters for Date_Received. When the @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 1 then I want the Date_Received months 10,11,12. If @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 2 then I want the Date_Received months 1,2,3 etc. SQL Server doesn't like the BETWEEN part of this. Thanks

```
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodQuarter Int

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
        MONTH(Date_Received) =
        CASE 
            WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 1 THEN BETWEEN 10 AND 12 
            WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 2 THEN BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
            WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 3 THEN BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
            WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 4 THEN BETWEEN 7 AND 9 
        END
```

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression** not a `Case` (`Switch`) statement; it returns a scalar value not a boolean result (or half of one in this case). Don't, however, use a `CASE` expression in your `WHERE`, stick to `AND` and `OR` operators.

Comment: Cute syntax but yeah no. `CASE` expressions do not yield booleans and cannot be compared. You would have to write `(@ReviewPeriodQuarter = 1 AND MONTH(Date_Received) BETWEEN 10 AND 12) OR (@ReviewPeriodQuarter = 2 AND MONTH(Date_Received) BETWEEN 1 AND 3) ...`

Comment: A for creativity and F for execution then? So many cool ways of solving this. thanks for the help

Comment: Will there ever be data from several years in the table? Since you have no filter on year in the `where` clause it will cheerfully merge data from _every_ February into Q2 as far back as the data goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it with more parameters like Larnu or you can use your original method but tweaked

```sql
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodQuarter INT

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE MONTH(Date_Received) BETWEEN 
CASE 
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 1 THEN 10
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 2 THEN 1
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 3 THEN 4
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 4 THEN 7
END 
AND 
CASE 
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 1 THEN 12
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 2 THEN 3
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 3 THEN 6
    WHEN @ReviewPeriodQuarter = 4 THEN 9
END
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using a _searched_ [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) rather than a _simple_ `case`, e.g. `case @ReviewPeriodQuarter when 1 then 10 when 2 then 1 ... end`?

Answer (score 1):

I would, pesonally, move the ranges to outside the `SELECT` entirely, and then just use a simple `WHERE`:

```sql
DECLARE @MonthStart int,
        @MonthEnd int;

SELECT @MonthStart = CASE @ReviewPeriodQuarter WHEN 1 THEN 10,
                                               WHEN 2 THEN 1
                                               WHEN 3 THEN 4
                                               WHEN 4 THEN 7
                     END,
       @MonthEnd = CASE @ReviewPeriodQuarter WHEN 1 THEN 12,
                                             WHEN 2 THEN 3
                                             WHEN 3 THEN 6
                                             WHEN 4 THEN 9
                   END;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Table]
WHERE MONTH(Date_Received) BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd;
```

Note that this still won't be SARGable though, due to the use of `MONTH(Date_Received)` in the `WHERE`. I must admit, needing rows from a table for specific months, regardless of year, is a little odd. If that *is* your true requirement you might be better off "investing" in a Calendar Table you can `JOIN` to, and then just having a `WHERE` on the calendar table's `CalendarMonth` column; which *would* be SARGable.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `values()`?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t JOIN
     (VALUES (1, 10, 12),
             (2, 1, 3),
             (3, 4, 6),
             (4, 7, 9)
     ) v(ReviewPeriodQuarter, lo, hi)
     ON MONTH(t.Date_Received) BETWEEN v.lo AND v.hi AND
        v.ReviewPeriodQuarter = @ReviewPeriodQuarter;
```

Or even more simply:

```
WHERE DATEPART(quarter, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, t.Date_Received)) = @ReviewPeriodQuarter
```

In other words, you don't need conditional logic to specify each quarter.  You can just use date arithmetic.